# How can we count sub query use group by without pivot?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I need to create query that has below result.
I add my table for example for better understanding.

```
QTable:
           QID Name
           -------
            1    x  
            1    y   
            2    z     
FTable:
         QID FID 
         -------
          1    1  
          1    2   
          2    3   


Inner join with :


           FID Type
           -------
            1    1       
            1    2        
            1    3        
            1    4        
            2    2        
            2    3        
            2    3 
            3    1        
            3    3        
            3    3
```

I need to result like this:

```
 result:
     QID FID-Count Type(1)-count Type(2)-count Type(3)-count Type(4)-count
     -----------------------------------------------------------------
      1     2           1             2              3             1
      2     1           1             0              2             0
```

Thank u for help.

Comment: can there be only 4 types as above or more? if there can be more, then Pivoting with Dynamic SQL is the best way to write the query..Also please post your query ..

Answer (score 3):

Ususally you can emulate a pivot with GROUP BY and SUM+CASE:

```
SELECT 
   T1.QID,
   COUNT(DISTINCT T1.FID) as FIDCOUNT,
   SUM(CASE WHEN Type=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Type1Cnt,
   SUM(CASE WHEN Type=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Type2Cnt,
   SUM(CASE WHEN Type=3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Type3Cnt,
   SUM(CASE WHEN Type=4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Type4Cnt


FROM QFTable as T1
JOIN T2 ON 
   T1.FID=T2.FID
GROUP BY T1.QID
ORDER BY QID
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b5f6c/5)</kbd>